# On Wizard, Is it better to use Magic Weapon or Familiar(sparkflint)?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

So the Wizard gets the skill Magic Weapon that raises your dmg by 10% and this *IS* reflected in your DPS rating when you cast it.

A few levels later you get the Familiar which eventually gets Sparkflint that says it raises all attack dmg by 12%, however this is *NOT* reflected in your DPS rating.

So which is better? If Sparkflint is 2% better why is it not reflected in your DPS rating?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the familiar attack on its own? Wouldn't it be referring to that damage and not specifically your DPS damage?

Comment: The tooltip says "Summon a fiery Familiar that increases the damage of all attacks by 12% while Familiar is active. " Not increase just the familiar, ALL attacks.

Comment: Also, can your familiar be killed?  (I haven't gotten enough time with the game to unlock this yet)

Comment: No it cannot be hurt or killed.

Comment: Unruned Magic Weapon is giving 20% bonus currently anyway, so it's always going to be greater.

Comment: The tooltip says 10% so why is it 20?

Comment: @Svperstar a bug, I'd assume.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, it all comes down to your personal gameplay but if you are interested in max DPS my recommendation is using the **Magic Weapon** (10%  more dmg) and using the **Force Weapon Skill Rune** (`which increases the dmg bonus of Magic Weapon to 20% dmg and gives up to a 2% chance to Knockback any enemies hit`).

Comment: In the end I decided to put Elective Mode on and use both.

Answer (score 1):

For maximum DPS you can just use both abilities. Also the damage from my familiar does show under DPS within the character sheet.